# Remove Pins before displaying it on the map

Tags: ios, route-me

before displaying Pins on the map, i have to make sure to remove them from the map so that it will never be over displayed because the procedure of displaying is placed in the `viewWillAppear` method. My relevant code is this :

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

            //before doing anything, i want to remove all Pins
            RMMarkerManager *markerManager=[mapView markerManager];
            [mapView setDelegate:self];
        [mapView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [mapView moveToLatLong:currentLocation];
        [mapView.contents setZoom: 13];
        [self.view addSubview:mapView];
        RMMarker *marker=[[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker-blue.png"]];
        [marker setTextForegroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [marker changeLabelUsingText:@"Vous êtes ici"];
        [markerManager addMarker:marker
                       AtLatLong:currentLocation];
    [marker release];
    }
```

How can i do that please? thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can just be done by calling the `removeMarkers` method of the `RMMarkerManager`, so it will be this :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    //remove all markers before starting    
    RMMarkerManager *markerManager=[mapView markerManager];
    [markerManager removeMarkers];

    //do what ever you want...

}
```